# New App keeps crashing over and over

Tags: android

so I build a structure for my new app. I have a swipe view in combination to a navigation drawer and not much coding experience. If I want to launch my app it crashes. I got this error:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: de.lukas_schroederoutlook.connect, PID: 2357
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.lukas_schroederoutlook.connect/de.lukas_schroederoutlook.connect.Overview_Screen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachController(FragmentManager.java:2137)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.attachHost(FragmentController.java:104)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:317)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:88)
                      at de.lukas_schroederoutlook.connect.Overview_Screen.onCreate(Overview_Screen.java:78)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

And this is my main activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Overview_Screen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview_screen);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer);


        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);

        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();


        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_overview_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent settings_intent = new Intent(this, Settings_Screen.class);
            startActivity(settings_intent);
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }


        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview_screen, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText("replace with something useful");
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = SecondFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = ThirdFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = FirstFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();


        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    // ...
}
```

In Android Studio there's nothing underlined or such. I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: What happens if you remove line 78:
 mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

Comment: still keeps crashing

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues inside of you `onCreate` method. The main issue is you're calling the super class for `onCreate` twice. Also you are setting the support `actionBar` twice and `setContent` twice. It should look something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview_screen);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the swipe view fragment causes this issue as it it 'empty'?